# iOS fetching data from server inside for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, nsurlsession

I want to fetch data from server with multiple calls inside for loop. I'm passing different parameter each time. I know it is possible to fetch data like, I'm fetching in code below :

```
for (NSDictionary *feedItem in [feed objectForKey:@"content"]) {
    // url with feedItem data.
    NSURL *url = ....
    [UrlMethod GetURL:url success:^(NSDictionary *placeData) {
        if (placeData) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // adding object to table data source array
                [dataSourceArray addObject:[placeData objectForKey:@"data"]];
                // reloading table view.
                [self.tableView reloadData];

                });
            }
       } failure:^(NSError *error) {

       }];
}
```

The problem is, Whenever I add data to dataSourceArry, It is not adding sequentially. It is adding according to response of API calls. Please let me know, If it is not clear.

Comment: There are lots of SO posts out there, did you check those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I would allocate a mutable array first and set [NSNull null] at each position:

```
NSInteger count = [[feed objectForKey:@"content"] count];
NSMutableArray *dataSourceArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    [dataSourceArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
```

Then, I would use something called dispatch groups (see more here http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/):

```
__block NSError *apiCallError = nil; // Just to keep track if there was at least one API call error
NSInteger index = 0;

// Create the dispatch group
dispatch_group_t serviceGroup = dispatch_group_create();

for (NSDictionary *feedItem in [feed objectForKey:@"content"]) {

    // Start a new service call
    dispatch_group_enter(serviceGroup);

    // url with feedItem data.
    NSURL *url = ...

    [UrlMethod GetURL:url success:^(NSDictionary *placeData) {
        if (placeData) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Add data to Data Source
                // index should be the correct one, as the completion block will contain a snapshot of the corresponding value of index
                dataSourceArray[index] = [placeData objectForKey:@"data"];
            }

            dispatch_group_leave(serviceGroup);
       } failure:^(NSError *error) {
           apiCallError = error;
           dispatch_group_leave(serviceGroup);
       }];

     index++; 
}

dispatch_group_notify(serviceGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    if (apiCallError) {
        // Make sure the Data Source contains no [NSNull null] anymore
        [dataSourceArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];
    }

    // Reload Table View
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Finally somebody wrote more accurate answer :) Felt sad I was counting I'll be the one to post the code using dispatch_group :) Anyway great job sir :) Not sure will this be accepted as answer but its 100% accurate :) Perfect use of dispatch_group :) hence up vote :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably use an NSDictionary with the slot number as a key instead, because that lets you check the status with [dict count].

Answer (score 1):

This might be of help for you,

```
 //keep dictionary property which will store responses
    NSMutableDictionary *storeResponses = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    //Somewhere outside function keep count or for loop
    NSInteger count = 0;

    for (NSDictionary *feedItem in [feed objectForKey:@"content"]) {
        //Find out index of feddItem
        NSInteger indexOfFeedItem = [[feed objectForKey:@"content"] indexOfObject:feedItem];

        NSString *keyToStoreResponse = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexOfFeedItem];

        // url with feedItem data.
        NSURL *url = ....
        [UrlMethod GetURL:url success:^(NSDictionary *placeData) {
            if (placeData) {
                //instead of storing directly to array like below
                // adding object to table data source array
                [dataSourceArray addObject:[placeData objectForKey:@"data"]];

                //follow this
                //increase count
                count++;
                [storeResponses setObject:[placeData objectForKey:@"data"] forKey:keyToStoreResponse];


                // reloading table view.
                if(count == [feed objectForKey:@"content"].count)
                {
                    NSMutableArray *keys = [[storeResponses allKeys] mutableCopy]; //or AllKeys
                    //sort this array using sort descriptor
                    //after sorting "keys"

                    for (NSString *key in keys)
                    {
                        //add them serially

                        [dataSourceArray addObject:[storeResponses objectForKey:key]];
                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


                        [self.tableView reloadData];



                    });
                }

            }
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {

        }];
    }
```

**Edit :** The answer I have given is directly written here,you might face compilation errors while actually running this code

Comment: Please don't just post a bunch of code with no explanation. A good answer explains what the problem is and it explains how the answer solves the issue.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the remark,but rains knows what is the problem and I have added a lot of comments in code, to help understand proposed solution.If you still feel the need to edit answer,you can go ahead and edit my answer or let me know what you feel and I'll update according to that.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're calling web-services asynchronously so it's not give guarantee that it's give response in sequence as you have made request!

Now solutions for that :

- You should write your `api` like it's give all data at a time. So,
  You not need to make many network call and it will improve
  performance also!
- Second thing you can make recursive kind of function, I mean make another request from `completion handler` of previous one. In this case once you got response then only another request will be initialize but in this case you will have to compromise with performance!! So first solution is better according to me!
- Another thing you can sort your array after you get all the responses and then you can reload your `tableView`

Comment: I would too suggest you to  go with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :-

```
    for (NSDictionary *feedItem in [feed objectForKey:@"content"]) {
        // url with feedItem data.
        NSURL *url = ....
        [UrlMethod GetURL:url success:^(NSDictionary *placeData) {
            if (placeData) {

                    // adding object to table data source array
                    [dataSourceArray addObject:[placeData objectForKey:@"data"]];
                    // reloading table view.
 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
                    });

           } failure:^(NSError *error) {

           }];
    }
```

Comment: @ppalancica Thanks !!

Comment: How is this answer supposed to solve the issue? It is actually worse.

Comment: And the completion blocks are not guaranteed to be invoked in the same order as the loops starts making the requests, that was his main concern. Your code is almost identical with his and wrong. You change dataSourceArray (which is probably a nonatomic property, therefore not thread safe) on a background thread as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reload your table each time in the loop. After the loop finishes fetching data , do a sorting on your datasourcearray to get the desired result and then reload table.